# What is the best practice for a bash script running psql commands in the background?

Tags: bash, sh, psql

I have been testing the connectivity and stability of a product, and part of my testing has been to open up 8 terminal windows, and fire off a script that uses psql to query a remote database 10 times, grabbing 50k rows per query. I have alias'd the command because I time it, log the results to another file, etc. **Right here I will admit I am not sure if this is good practice or not, I'm somewhat new to bash profiles and the rest.** It was getting pretty annoying to click through the 8 windows (all inside one larger window), and so I thought I would try using "&" to just fire it off 10 times in the background. This has proven to be problematic, and far less successful than manually telling 8 windows to fire up the script. Mainly, the window where I'm doing "& & & & etc" never "returns", and I have to CTRL-C to get back to prompt. Additionally, I get a lot more server errors from psql. Here are the two commands I'm running, somewhat obfuscated and abbreviated:

```
test="(time bash ~/Documents/some/other/folders/myPsql.sh) >> \
~/Documents/some/stuff/logfile.txt 2>&1 && echo done"

shortcut="test & test & test & test & test & test & test & test & test & test"
```

Here is the psql script which works fine when ran via "test" command above:

```
psql << EOF
\pset pager off
\pset timing on
\copy (select * from sometable limit 50000) to '~/Documents/some/folder/file.csv' csv;
\q
EOF
```

I am fairly new to a lot of the moving parts at work here, and so I recognize that something I am doing might be fundamentally flawed in some way.

Is there any "good"/better way to make my "shortcut" command above more successful?

EDIT: This was the error I was referring to:

> psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly 
>   This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>   before or while processing the request.

I'm using iTerm2 on Mac, and psql is "talking to" a local software client, which is interacting with other software on Predix (CloudFoundry) to query a Postgres db, also on Predix.

Comment: Code shouldn't be stored in strings at all. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: As for "server errors" -- what's the platform? If you're on an operating system such as Windows where having multiple concurrent writers to the same file is disallowed-by-default, there are going to be a bunch of extra failures related to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` is a standardized shell command. Overwriting it with your own names is going to break rather a lot of scripts/functions/etc.

```
psqlTest() {
  # DANGER: This filename can be used for SQL injection attacks. Keep it under control.
  local outFile=${1:-~/Documents/some/folder/file.csv}

  psql <<EOF
\\pset pager off
\\pset timing on
\\copy (select * from sometable limit 50000) to '$outFile' csv;
\\q
EOF
}

parallelPsqlTest() {
  local count=${1:-10}  # if not given a number, start 10 versions of our test
  for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do
    psqlTest &
  done
}
```

Some notes:

- Don't store commands in strings. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).
- `~` is meaningful to the shell, but *not* to most other programs. Thus, you want to have it expanded (replaced with `/home/whatever` or `/Users/whatever`) *before* the shell starts whichever software a path is being passed to.
- Substituting variables into SQL text is a Very Bad Idea. See [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). This is true even for filenames -- filenames on UNIX can contain quotes, can contain newlines, and can otherwise have a bunch of contents you probably assume they can't.
- Don't use the name `test` for your own commands: It's the normal name for the command also known as `[`, specified at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html
- The backslashes inside the heredoc need to be doubled to ensure that they are passed to `psql` and not interpreted by the shell itself.

Comment: Thanks Charles! I'm not sure why I hid/changed my naming convention, but I wasn't actually using "test" or "shortcut". I am going to try to implement what you have here, this makes sense!

Comment: BTW, if you want to wait for all the processes you start to complete before proceeding, that's a job for capturing `$!` after each background process is forked and then invoking `wait` for each in turn. (If you just call `wait` without a specific PID you wait for everything, but don't get details on which / how many succeeded or failed).

Comment: At least as of PostGres 9.6, you can use (I think; untested) `psql -v out="${outFile}" <<EOF ... to :'out' csv; ...` to guard against SQL injection.